# Checking if theres multiple of a specific character in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if the list has one :, then it'll pass, but if it has more then it'll return false. I'm unsure of how to do this. I've tried stripping thelist with the characters, but doesnt seem to work.

```
def checker(thelist):
    checked = re.search('[a-zA-Z, |^&+\-%*/=!]', thelist)
    if ":, :" in thelist:
        print("test")
    else:
        if checked == None:
            x = True
        else:
            x = False
        return x
```

Comment: why don't use `count` method?

Comment: Is `theList` a list or a string? The argument to `re.search()` has to be a string.

Comment: Please make this a running example by calling checker with sample data. You were asked a very reasonable question and that would show us the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the *count* method.

Count how many times a word is in your string:

```
yourWord = "hello : some text here :"
wordCounter = yourWord.count(":")
```

**wordCounter = 2**

Now you should be able to do what you want with some if statement.